# error parsing response from POST on /todos

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am not able to parse the json data from this method. i am getting an error "error parsing response from POST on /todos"   that is printed in the method. will anybody please guid me to post the proper data with POST method and to have to proper result ?

```
func callAddWithPOST(Name mname:String, PhoneNo mphone:String, Email memail:String, Comment mcomments:String)
{

    let d_mname = mname
    let d_phoneno = mphone
    let d_email = memail
    let d_Comment = mcomments

    let Urlpost: String! = "http://smartrestaurants.com/RestaurantAPI.asmx/addTestimonial"

    let urlforpost = NSURL(string: Urlpost)
    let todosUrlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: urlforpost!)
    todosUrlRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    let newTodo = ["reviewId": 111, "restaurantId": 93, "customerId": 143, "locationId": 393, "name": d_mname, "phone": d_phoneno, "email": d_email, "comment": d_Comment, "creationdate": "1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM"]

    let jsonTodo: NSData
    do {
        jsonTodo = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(newTodo, options: [])
        todosUrlRequest.HTTPBody = jsonTodo
    } catch {
        print("Error: cannot create JSON from todo")
        return
    }
    todosUrlRequest.HTTPBody = jsonTodo

    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(todosUrlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) in
        guard let responseData = data else {
            print("Error: did not receive data")
            return
        }
        guard error == nil else {
            print("error calling POST on /todos/1")
            print(error)
            return
        }
        do {
            guard let receivedTodo = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject] else
            {
                print("Could not get JSON from responseData as dictionary")
                return
            }
            print("The todo is: " + receivedTodo.description)

            guard let todoID = receivedTodo["name"] as? String else {
                print("Could not get todoID as int from JSON")
                return
            }
            print("The ID is: \(todoID)")
        }
        catch
        {
            print("error parsing response from POST on /todos")
            return
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: can you show how is your json result look like?

Comment: Done Editing
Your Email : test
Your Email : Zanakhana Ruparelia Patel
Your Email : Boney
Your Email : James Bond
error parsing response from POST on /todos
test
123123
test@test.com
test

Comment: Above is output of the code. will anybody please guide me to fix this issue ?